# Pin text to bottom of scroll view SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, vstack

How can I pin a view element to the bottom of a scrollview/VStack in SwiftUI? I've tried using spacers but that doesn't seem to be working. I need the 'Footer' text to be at the bottom of the scroll view/Vstack, how can I do that?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Top Title")
                    Text("Body")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Footer") // SHOULD BE PINNED TO BOTTOM OF SCROLL VIEW
                        .frame(alignment: .bottom)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.red)

            Button("Done") {
                //some action
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you require that it be inside the scroll view? Otherwise you could just put it with the done button.

Comment: @JustMakeStuff yes I want it in the scroll view

Comment: Do you want it to scroll up when the user scrolls or do you want it to stay pinned?

Answer (score 8):

Here is possible approach:

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Top Title")
        Text("Body")
    }
}
.overlay(
    Text("Footer") 
, alignment: .bottom)   // << here !!
```

Guess 2: probably you wanted this

```
GeometryReader { gp in
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Top Title")
            Text("Body")
            Spacer()
            Text("Footer") // SHOULD BE PINNED TO BOTTOM OF SCROLL VIEW
                .frame(alignment: .bottom)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: gp.size.height)
    }
    .background(Color.red)
}
```

Comment: The issue is that this does not scroll with the content

Comment: wait, you said "pin", pined and scrolled are mutually exclusive, no?

Answer (score 1):

You are properly looking for the `safeAreaInset` modifier: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/safeareainset(edge:alignment:spacing:content:)-6gwby

Comment: A great solution but not available before iOS 15. Asperi's solution works for iOS 14 as well.